# What is the difference between Digg Diggs and Saved?

Tags: digg

[image]

In Digg Reader, there are Diggs and Saved.

And when you are reading an article, there is an option to Digg it or Save it.

These seems identical to me so far. As if they should be named Save 1 and Save 2.

Is there some other feature which differentiates these two?

Answer (score 1):

Difference is that with Diggs you are publicly upvoting the article or feed item which feeds into what would end up on the main digg.com site based on popularity.

Saves are for your personal stash, and are not used (at least so far) to rank the items that appear on digg.com proper.

Comment: And can a vote be traced back to me personally?

Comment: At a glance, without looking into their API or other methods, that doesn't seem public as yet